# "outer join" parent without ref

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have the following mongoose models (excerpted):

```
var subscriberSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  address: String
});
var Subscriber = mongoose.model('Subscriber', subscriberSchema);

var magazineSchema = new Schema({
  title: String
});
var Magazine = mongoose.model('Magazine', magazineSchema);

var subscriptionSchema = new Schema({
  owner: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Subscriber'},
  magazine: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Magazine'},
  metadata like price, start date, end date: ...
});
var Subscription = mongoose.model('Subscription', subscriptionSchema);
```

and I have an express route which shows the user a list of magazines:

```
let magazines = await Magazine.find();
if (!magazines) return next(err);

res.render('magazines', {
  magazines: magazines
});
```

In this route, I would like to join the magazines with the subscriptions, if the user has a subscription with that magazine.

In sql this would be an outer join,

```
select *
from magazines
outer join subscriptions
  where subscriptions.magazine_id = magazine.id
    and owner_id = $current_user_id
```

Other questions/answers on StackOverflow assume that the child schema (`magazine`) would have a `_creator` ref to the `subscriber`. But this is not the case here. Subscribers and Magazines are their own entities and they should have no direct ref to eachother, only through the `subscription` has-many-through model.

How would I do this in mongoose?

Comment: For outer join, the MongoDB's Aggregation Framework could be used here to resolve your issue. please refer to this https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I consider the "naive" approach, doing two queries then joining them together in plain javascript.

```
  let magazines = await Magazine.find().lean();
  if (!magazines) return next(err);

  if (req.user) {
    let subscriptions = await Subscription.find({owner: req.user}).lean();
    let subscriptionsLookup = _.keyBy(subscriptions, 'magazine');
    magazines.forEach((magazine) => {
      if (magazine._id in subscriptionsLookup) {
        magazine.subscription = subscriptionsLookup[magazine._id];
      }
    });
  }

res.render('magazines', {
  layout: false,
  magazines: magazines
});
```

Now the view can check if a magazine is already subscribed by the user.

I feel that this approach is heavy-handed. I am submitting this as an answer because, well, it is *an* answer. I don't want this to be the best answer. It's just the approach I have so far.